Notification Panel Displays When App is Pinned - Anyone Else Experienced This?
I've encountered an issue where the notification panel always displays when the app is pinned (Kiosk mode), after tapping the notification panel. Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions for resolving this would be appreciated.
Thank you
I haven't tried anything yet, but I am still searching for the same issue.
